# Importing class gives runtime errors

Tags: python, python-import, keras

I'm trying to work with [this](https://github.com/raghakot/keras-resnet) class to build res nets.

When running the resnet.py, the main function runs and I get expected results. The main function looks like this:

```
def main():
    model = ResNetBuilder.build_resnet_18((3, 224, 224), 1000)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="sgd")
    model.summary()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When importing the function, I get runtime errors. Minimal example:

```
from resnet import ResNetBuilder

from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

model = ResNetBuilder.build_resnet_18((3, 224, 224), 1000)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="sgd")
model.summary()
```

The errors are runtime errors about sizes of layers or dividing by zero - I feel like I must be doing something really stupid import-wise but can't quite see it..?

Output:

```
Using Theano backend.
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 750 Ti (CNMeM is disabled, cuDNN 5105)
/......./site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py:1500: UserWarning: DEPRECATION: the 'ds' parameter is not going to exist anymore as it is going to be replaced by the parameter 'ws'.
  mode='max')
/......./site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py:1500: UserWarning: DEPRECATION: the 'st' parameter is not going to exist anymore as it is going to be replaced by the parameter 'stride'.
  mode='max')
/......./site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py:1500: UserWarning: DEPRECATION: the 'padding' parameter is not going to exist anymore as it is going to be replaced by the parameter 'pad'.
  mode='max')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testResnet.py", line 6, in <module>
    model = ResNetBuilder.build_resnet_18((3, 224, 224), 1000)
  File "........resnet.py", line 154, in build_resnet_18
    return ResNetBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, basic_block, [2, 2, 2, 2])
  File "........resnet.py", line 139, in build
    block = _residual_block(block_fn, nb_filters=nb_filters, repetitions=r, is_first_layer=i == 0)(block)
  File "........resnet.py", line 77, in f
    input = block_function(nb_filters=nb_filters, init_subsample=init_subsample)(input)
  File "........resnet.py", line 90, in f
    return _shortcut(input, residual)
  File "........resnet.py", line 65, in _shortcut
    init="he_normal", border_mode="valid")(input)
  File "/......./site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 514, in __call__
    self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/......./site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 572, in add_inbound_node
    Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/......./site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 152, in create_node
    output_shapes = to_list(outbound_layer.get_output_shape_for(input_shapes[0]))
  File "/......./site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 451, in get_output_shape_for
    self.border_mode, self.subsample[0])
  File "/......./site-packages/keras/utils/np_utils.py", line 131, in conv_output_length
    return (output_length + stride - 1) // stride
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a full traceback showing the problem or at least one instance of it occurring.

Comment: Why are you manually setting the image dimension ordering?

Comment: Keras can use either Theano or Tensorflow and they have different ordering conventions - Theano uses [channels, rows, cols], Tensorflow uses [rows, cols, channels]. That definitely works and I have checked that the backend is properly set by printing it from within the class methods